# How to check if I have setup graphic card for 4K monitor?

Tags: thinkpad, 4k-monitor

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Thinkpad P51 with 4K monitor.
I would like to check that 4K monitor work correctly, because it seems that it doesn't work right.

If this can help:

```
 lshw -c video

>   *-display               
>        description: 3D controller
>        product: NVIDIA Corporation
>        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>        version: a1
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
>        configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
>        resources: irq:316 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff
> ioport:d000(size=128) memory:ec000000-ec07ffff   *-display
>        description: VGA compatible controller
>        product: Intel Corporation
>        vendor: Intel Corporation
>        physical id: 2
>        bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>        version: 04
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>        configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>        resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:317 memory:2ff2000000-2ff2ffffff memory:2fc0000000-2fcfffffff
> ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I never had before a 4K monitor so I am not sure. Resolution should be 3840x2160 but checking browser width of a website page I can see  1861x2003.2. Ubuntu screen setting also sow 3840x2160, so I am not sure why a website page is lower.

Comment: What makes you assume something is wrong with your monitor? Please edit our question to contain information about the problem you are seeing and what you tried already to fix it.

Comment: I have add more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All work fine. I see different size of a webpage because of scale set to 2 by default. Changing scale to 1 show correct. But effect is terrible small, so I understand why default scale is 2.